# How to use thread module in OCaml

Tags: multithreading, ocaml

I want to use the thread module in OCaml but I can't open it.
For example, with Unix I have to use : `#load "unix.cma";;`
or `#load "graphics.cma";;` for graphics module.

But when I try `#load "thread.cma"` it return an error.

How can I load it ?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Cannot find file thread.cma

Answer (score 9):

Contrarily to `unix.cma` or `graphics.cma`, `threads.cma` (with a final `s`: `Thread` is only one of the module contained in the `threads.cma` library) does not reside directly in OCaml's standard library directory, but in the `threads` subdirectory, so that you have to add it to the search path of the interpreter. Moreover, `threads.cma` depends on `unix.cma`, so that you have to load it as well. All in all, the following sequence of directives should allow you to have `threads.cma` loaded in the interpreter (the `+` indicates that `threads` is a subdirectory of the standard library).

```
#directory "+threads";;
#load "unix.cma";;
#load "threads.cma";;
```

Note that if you install [`findlib`](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/findlib.html), and `#use "topfind";;` (directive which can be put in your `~/.ocamlinit` file), then using threads in the interpreter is just a matter of typing `#thread;;`, not to mention the fact that accessing other libraries becomes also much easier.